# azure pipeline TFVC check if a specific Build pipeline artifacts exist for a specific Branch name and specific tag

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps services and TFVC as my code repository.
I have a build that has a task type "Download build artifacts" (Download files that were saved as artifacts of a completed build).
What i need to check is if there are saved artifacts of a specific completed build for a specific Branch name and tag? because if there isn't the task will fail and i want to fall to a default artifact.

Thanks

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Does below suggestion is help for you? Free to comment if you still has any puzzle or question.

Comment: Sorry for just noticing now about your comment. Though it doesn't help me. It gave me a new direction for solving the problem and I think in an efficient way. I will create the task that you wrote below and enable/run it only if the previous task failed. Which will give me a fallback to the default Artifact i wanted. There is another solution, use REST API queries to check if there is an artifact for a specific branch. I will check the solution and write an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just define this task like this:

```
steps:
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    buildType: specific
    project: '{project name}'
    pipeline: {pipeline name}
    buildVersionToDownload: latestFromBranch
    branchName: '{Branch name, e.g. $/TFVC}'
    tags: {the tag you want to filtered}
    downloadType: specific
    downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

In this task definition, the most key parameters is the `branchname` because you are using a **TFVC** repos.

[image]

Comment: inline `What i need to check is if there are saved artifacts of a specific completed build for a specific Branch name and tag.because if there isn't the task will fail and i want to fall to a default artifact.`
 So the question was about how to find out whether specific artifact exist. At your example the task will fail

Comment: YAML builds don't support TFVC.

Comment: @DanielMann, But I am suggesting cx to configure task with Classic UI INSTEAD of YAML. Since screenshot is not not good to view all arguments, I just show it  to this cx as **View as YAML**